# Using databases with elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy my Django based questionnaire application on AWS. I'm completely new to AWS and web apps for that matter.

When I built my app it was running fine on localserver and I used this in my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I have managed to successfuly deploy my application using elastic beanstalk, and it was working fine. But then I had to make some changes in my code and i used 'eb deploy' from my local directory to deploy the new version.

This lead to the loss of all the data(the responses filled till now). I realised I need to do something about my database. Since I'm completely new to all this, some help and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of sqlite (which is localised to a machine), setup a remote mysql/postgresql/maria etc. server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Man, I had this experience in the past and do not have good news for you. The worst part was that no one told me what I'll tell you now. What means that I spent a lot of time before understanding what are occurring...

Think on this: When you create an elastic beanstalk environment, AWS provide everything for you: instances, eb volumes, load balancers and all. When you upload a revision, using console or AWS cli, AWS recreate your instance from scratch,  based on a elastic beanstalk image. This means that every data saved on the disk of your environment will be throwed away. The new environment will be initialized with an "empty" disk (so and platform files will be there). This means: your database will be living in heaven or in the hell, based on what you saved on it.

If you need to keep your data after instance termination/reinitialization, you must configure an extra elastic block storage or an elastic file system. But for this to work you must change your initialization scripts to attach the block storage or the filesystem after initialization. And keep in mind that Elastic Beanstalk is a bit brute when terminating/reinilizating instances. If your database need some procedures to shutdown correctly, eb will just let it cry (comment based on personal experience).

The best practice on this case is install your database in a different instance and keep it running independent of your application environment. In this situation you can forget about the database when you deploy a new revision.

Check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.design.html) for more information.

Comment: lol thanks for the heads up man! i think i'm gonna work it out on amazon RDS and see where life takes me ~_~

Answer (score 0):

is True .. aws is overwritting .. and if you use the local database you will lose some data..
my advice.. use RDS from AWS and configure a database or use Elastic B console to associate a data base.. see Configuration/DATABASES..
this way your data will be on different instance and you will not lose it...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html

here is explained pretty well ..