# Create permanent directory in AWS elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a folder called `keys` in the `\etc` directory of my AWS eb environment by using SSH to access the environment. However, whenever I restart/create a new instance of my eb environment, this user-defined directory `keys` is deleted. How can I avoid this happening and make sure that the folder is permanent?

Comment: Please, check the answer or the  following question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864231/using-databases-with-elastic-beanstalk/44866378#44866378

Comment: You could have an `ebextensions` script that will create that directory on each new instance, but any files you store in there will be lost. If you want to keep files across Elastic Beanstalk deployments/restarts you have to store them somewhere else like S3 or EFS.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030090/7661119. I see that there is another answer linked above, which goes slightly off-topic, in my opinion.